# Set-NaCifsShareAcl is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cifs

I am trying to run Set-NaCifsShareAcl to set permissions on a CIFS share for iis_usrs account, but get the error 
'Set-NaCifsShareAcl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Anybody know where I can get this utility or how I should run it?

Thanks much for any suggestions/comments

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to import the netapp Data ONTAP PowerShell Module:

https://communities.netapp.com/docs/DOC-6248

The toolkit is free for customers and partners

http://www.netapp.com/de/communities/tech-ontap/de-tot-december-ontap-power-shell-toolkit.aspx